# eLearning writing: Beginning with “while”

Tags: sentence-construction, tense, usage

I am aware that using *While* to begin a sentence brings in a dimension of time to it.

[image]

Could you please tell me if this sentence is grammatically correct?

Thank you.

Comment: What makes you doubt it?

Comment: @RonaldSole : The first part of the sentence has a time element to it, but the second part does not. Hence, I'm very confused.

Comment: Please type the text instead of linking an image.

Answer (score 5):

"While" has a secondary use that has nothing to do with time. It can also mean "*despite the fact that; although*".

> While [x] is true, [y] is also true.

... could also be written as...

> Although [x] is true, [y] is also true.

---

A time-related example would be:

> While John cleaned the house, Jane stayed in bed.

This means that these two things happened at the same time.